# Максимально эффективный алгоритм поиска суммы делителей числа

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Собственно сабж. Акцент на эффективность. Тупо перебор или поиск до корня или n/2 не предлагать.

С меня пиво победителю.

P.S. хинтом может быть что сами делители не нужны, только их сумма

Comment: почему ты думаешь что перебор до корня не эффективен?

Comment: недостаточно эффективен, ибо это все равно перебор и на больших числах это жрет ресурсы неоправданно много

Comment: о каких числах идет речь? Добавь несколько примеров в вопрос входных данных и ожидаемого результата

Comment: порядок чисел - триллион и выше. число итераций - до 1 тыс.

Comment: тысяча каких итераций?

Comment: у меня была идея не квадратный корень юзать, а Х-ный и потом собирать его результаты рекурсивно, но не сработало...

Comment: тысяча каких итераций - любых, для поиска результата

Comment: подозреваю что ответ лежит где-то в области высшей математики, а не алгоритмике...

Comment: есть формула суммы через [произведение простых делителей](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function),  но чтобы сказать эффективнее это или нет нужно множество тестов, не синтетических

Comment: Как выглядит точное условие задачи?

Answer (score 5):

Разложите число в произведение простых сомножителей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда [сумма сомножителей равна](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Elementary_Number_Theory_(Raji)/04%3A_Multiplicative_Number_Theoretic_Functions/4.02%3A_Multiplicative_Number_Theoretic_Functions)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сложность задачи упирается в сложность разложения на простые множители. Магии нет. Например, ро-метод Полларда будет работать в среднем за корень четвёртой степени из `N`, но в худших случаях за квадратный корень.

Увы, от квадратного корня не уйти. Можно попытаться через всякие разные эвристики попытаться выделить случаи больших простых делителей, например сразу проверять N на простоту или на произведение близких делителей (когда `N = (n-1)(n+1)`), но сложность задачи для случая больших чисел всё равно останется порядка корня из `N`/

Пример вычисления суммы делителей через разложение на простые сомножители. Для поиска делителей используется пакет `primefac`

```py
import math
from primefac import multifactor, isprime, ispower


def factor(n):
    # Возвращает список простых делителей
    dividers = []
    while n > 1 and not isprime(n):
        p, _ = multifactor(n)
        p = simplify(p)
        while n % p == 0:
            n = n // p
            dividers.append(p)
    if n > 1:
        dividers.append(n)
    return dividers


def simplify(p):
    # Некоторые методы возвращают степень простого делителя
    # В этой функции возвращается собственно простой делитель
    while not isprime(p):
        pp = ispower(p)
        if pp is None:
            # Некоторые методы возвращают непростой делитель
            divs = factor(p)
            return divs[0]
        if isinstance(pp, tuple):
            p, _ = pp
            continue
        if isinstance(pp, int):
            if pp > 0:
                p = pp
            else:
                return p
    return p


def sum_1_brute(n):
    # Вычисляет сумму делителей перебором
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            # Если i - делитель, то n/i тоже делитель
            result += i + n // i
    return result


def sum_1(dividers):
    # Вычисляет сумму делителей из простых делителей
    dividers = sorted(dividers)
    muls = []
    P = 1
    last = 1
    for p in dividers + [0]:
        if p == last:
            P *= p
        else:
            if last != 1:
                P = (P - 1) // (last - 1)
                muls.append(P)
            last = p
            P = p * p
            if p == 0:
                break
    result = 1
    for P in muls:
        result *= P
    return result
```

```py
def test(n):
    dividers = factor(n)
    print(n, "=", " * ".join([str(p) for p in dividers]))
    print("sum_1(", n, ") = ", sum_1(dividers))

for n in [
    625,
    1021,
    1023,
    1024,
    12345678901,
    1111222222222222222132191110000000000000089789,
    90377629292003121684002147101760858109247336549001090677693,
]:
    test(n)
```

Результаты:

```
625 = 5 * 5 * 5 * 5
sum_1( 625 ) =  781
1021 = 1021
sum_1( 1021 ) =  1022
1023 = 3 * 11 * 31
sum_1( 1023 ) =  1536
1024 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
sum_1( 1024 ) =  2047
12345678901 = 857 * 14405693
sum_1( 12345678901 ) =  12360085452
1111222222222222222132191110000000000000089789 = 99999999999999999991999 * 11112222222222222222211
sum_1( 1111222222222222222132191110000000000000089789 ) =  1111222222222222222132302222222222222222304000
90377629292003121684002147101760858109247336549001090677693 = 773951836515617 * 260938498861057 * 588120598053661 * 760926063870977
sum_1( 90377629292003121684002147101760858109247336549001090677693 ) =  90377629292003857259428190545028277496848034773041535999984
```

## К вопросу об эффективности

До чисел порядка 10^12 перебор делителей работает быстрее, чем разложение на множители. Правда, надо признать, что `primefac` не заточен под супер-эффективность. Вполне возможно, что для этого диапазона можно сделать более эффективный перебор по таблице простых чисел (решето Эратосфена).

Зато после `10^14` разложение на простые множители начинает уверенно обгонять. После `10^20` перебор делителей дождаться нереально. А разложение на простые работает.

`primefac` начинает испытывать трудности после `10^40`. Методы, которые реализованы в этой библиотеке, для столь больших чисел начинают тупить.

```
n = 1, 10^1
sum_1:           0:00:00.000049
brute force:     0:00:00.000017
n = 12, 10^2
sum_1:           0:00:00.010852
brute force:     0:00:00.000012
n = 123, 10^3
sum_1:           0:00:00.003945
brute force:     0:00:00.000017
n = 1234, 10^4
sum_1:           0:00:00.005437
brute force:     0:00:00.000024
n = 12345, 10^5
sum_1:           0:00:00.017756
brute force:     0:00:00.000037
n = 123456, 10^6
sum_1:           0:00:00.024261
brute force:     0:00:00.000026
n = 1234567, 10^7
sum_1:           0:00:00.006776
brute force:     0:00:00.000123
n = 12345678, 10^8
sum_1:           0:00:00.015340
brute force:     0:00:00.000249
n = 123456789, 10^9
sum_1:           0:00:00.014531
brute force:     0:00:00.000601
n = 1234567890, 10^10
sum_1:           0:00:00.031338
brute force:     0:00:00.003009
n = 12345678901, 10^11
sum_1:           0:00:00.005974
brute force:     0:00:00.009970
n = 123456789012, 10^12
sum_1:           0:00:00.012598
brute force:     0:00:00.030082
n = 1234567890123, 10^13
sum_1:           0:00:00.012654
brute force:     0:00:00.119792
n = 12345678901234, 10^14
sum_1:           0:00:00.012842
brute force:     0:00:00.300058
n = 123456789012345, 10^15
sum_1:           0:00:00.028803
brute force:     0:00:01.019764
n = 1234567890123456, 10^16
sum_1:           0:00:00.030952
brute force:     0:00:02.983313
n = 12345678901234567, 10^17
sum_1:           0:00:00.004127
brute force:     0:00:09.332171
n = 123456789012345678, 10^18
sum_1:           0:00:00.016758
brute force:     0:00:29.571767
n = 1234567890123456789, 10^19
sum_1:           0:00:00.029507
brute force:     0:01:47.490783
n = 12345678901234567890, 10^20
sum_1:           0:00:00.064231
brute force:     не дождался
n = 123456789012345678901, 10^21
sum_1:           0:00:00.014564
n = 1234567890123456789012, 10^22
sum_1:           0:00:00.036047
n = 12345678901234567890123, 10^23
sum_1:           0:00:00.011601
n = 123456789012345678901234, 10^24
sum_1:           0:00:00.028437
n = 1234567890123456789012345, 10^25
sum_1:           0:00:00.057464
n = 12345678901234567890123456, 10^26
sum_1:           0:00:00.031801
n = 123456789012345678901234567, 10^27
sum_1:           0:00:00.004544
n = 1234567890123456789012345678, 10^28
sum_1:           0:00:00.037674
n = 12345678901234567890123456789, 10^29
sum_1:           0:00:00.071782
n = 123456789012345678901234567890, 10^30
sum_1:           0:00:00.078789
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901, 10^31
sum_1:           0:00:00.841133
n = 12345678901234567890123456789012, 10^32
sum_1:           0:00:00.432267
n = 123456789012345678901234567890123, 10^33
sum_1:           0:00:00.019199
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234, 10^34
sum_1:           0:00:00.039726
n = 12345678901234567890123456789012345, 10^35
sum_1:           0:00:00.035497
n = 123456789012345678901234567890123456, 10^36
sum_1:           0:00:00.008347
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567, 10^37
sum_1:           0:00:00.029856
n = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678, 10^38
sum_1:           0:00:07.578845
n = 123456789012345678901234567890123456789, 10^39
sum_1:           0:00:00.076453
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890, 10^40
sum_1:           0:00:00.095464
n = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901, 10^41
sum_1:           0:00:00.046423
n = 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012, 10^42
sum_1:           0:00:22.430057
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123, 10^43
sum_1:           0:00:16.613241
n = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234, 10^44
sum_1:           0:00:00.221765
n = 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345, 10^45
sum_1:           0:00:00.146430
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456, 10^46
sum_1:           0:00:00.193912
n = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567, 10^47
sum_1:           0:00:15.346941
n = 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678, 10^48
sum_1:           0:00:00.040593
n = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789, 10^49
sum_1:           0:00:00.462669
```

Comment: разве просто поиск делителей не будет проще чем разложение на простые делители?

Comment: @Grundy Конечно нет. Для поиска всех делителей нужно перебирать числа до `sqrt(N)`. С простыми делителями проще. Как только вы нашли первый `p`, делите `N` на него и дальше ищите простые делители `N/p` - объем перебора резко сокращается. А в случае степеней простых чисел так и вообще. Пример: 1024 - простой делитель один, а вообще делителей 512.

Comment: ты исключаешь проверку на простоту самого делителя

Comment: @Grundy а что там сложного? Для небольших чисел проверка по таблицам простых. Для больших тест Миллера-Рабина.

Comment: Он же вероятностный - то есть не гарантирует что число простое

Comment: @Grundy я сейчас проверил на Core i7. Грубой силой, перебирая делители, vs раскладывая на делители средствами `primefac` -- разложение на множители обгоняет грубую силу начиная с `N ~ 10^11`. Для меньших чисел перебор делителей быстрее. Зато для чисел от `10^13` разложение на простые обгоняет на порядок.

Comment: А реализация на чем? На питоне была?